# SQL - Problem finding records in a range for multiple dates

Tags: sql-server, ssms

i am looking for a way to extract data with a lot of possible dates.

example list of dates:

```
declare @visitDate table (Id DATE)
insert into @visitDate values ('2009-04-02'), ('2019-04-08'), ('2020-01-23')
```

The records can be from 7 days before up to 7 days after the listed dates.
I tried doing it like:

```
 WHERE effectiveDateTime_date BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -7, '2009-04-02') AND DATEADD(day, +7, '2009-04-02')
```

Which works for a set date, but i can't seem to figure it out with a long list of dates to check. I have over 2000 dates, so i'd really prefer not them out in "or" statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join` or `exists`:

```
where exists (select 1
              from @visitDate vd
              where t.effectiveDateTime_date >= dateadd(day, -7, vd.id) and
                    t.effectiveDateTime_date <= dateadd(day, 7, vd.id)
             )
```